# $("#tabs").tabs() breaks file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple file upload which I want to include in a jquery tab using href. Unfortunately, it breaks in the tab.

The code is below.  If I comment out the $("#tabs").tabs(); in the containing code, it works; if not, file upload does not occur.

The file upload code, contained in a file called, upload.html, is as follows:

```
<html>
<body>
  <form name="registration" action="../php/recordInteraction.php" method="post" 
      accept-charset="utf-8" target="_self"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >  
  <div> 
     <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" >
     <p><label for="submit"> Hi</label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" > 
     </p> 
  </div> 
 </form> 
</body> </html>
```

The containing jquery code, small.html, is:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() { 
     $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
   }); 
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs" >
  <ul>
    <li><a id="upload" href="upload.html">Upload</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple jQuery solution.  When the link is clicked, jQuery clicks the file upload button.

*The jQuery is commented.*

```js
$('#uploadButton').click(function() { // when the tab is clicked

  $('#fileToUpload').click(); // pretend the file input was clicked

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>

  <a href="#" id="uploadButton">Browse for files</a>
  <br/><br/>

  <form name="registration" action="../php/recordInteraction.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" target="_self" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
      <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
      <p>
        <label for="submit">Hi</label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload">
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I had not explained the problem correctly. I've posted new code illustrating the problem.

Comment: @LenB, this code will work for your tab, too.  Simply change `$('#uploadButton')` to `$('#upload')`.

Comment: Turns out the problem was being caused by my use of the form attribute on the input element.  This was preventing the file from actually being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

what @God is good wrote is correct. you can also do it by directly submitting the form.

```
<html>
<body>
  <a href="#" id="uploadButton">Browse for files</a>
  <br/><br/>
  <form name="registration" action="../php/recordInteraction.php" method="post" 
  accept-charset="utf-8" target="_self"  enctype="multipart/form-data" **id="fileSubmitForm"**>  
  <div> 
     <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" >
     <p><label for="submit"> Hi</label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Upload" > 
    </p> 
  </div> 
 </form> 
</body> </html>

$('#uploadButton').click(function() { // when the tab is clicked

  $('#fileSubmitForm').submit(); // pretend the file input was clicked

});
```

Comment: I had not explained the problem correctly.  I've posted new code illustrating the problem.